# How to restore a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to restore a model using a `.ckpt` file, which I got by running `word2vec_optimized.py` in `tensorflow/models/embedding`. I am not sure how to go about restoring the variables so that I can load the model and use it because all of the tf variables are encapsulated and initialized in classes in `tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py`. Any help would be appreciated.

Also if I do "restore" the `.ckpt` created, do I now have a `Wor2Vec` instance or what do I actually get when I restore a model using a `.ckpt`?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the save function on your saver you pass it the tf.Session that you were using to train the model on.  This contains a reference to the graph which contains all the variables.  Don't confuse python variables with tensorflow variables. Even if you no longer have a variable in python which points to a tensorflow variable you created, it still exists if it is part of the computational graph.  After you create your model try running the following code.

```
for v in tf.all_variables():
    print(v.name)
```

This will print out the name of every variable you created.  The saver will by default save all of these.  So long as the variables have the same name when you restore them it does not matter where they were created.  Just make sure you do the restore after all variables have been added to the model.  When you give a variable an initializer the initialization is only run when you call  `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`.  You don't need to call this if you are just restoring the values.  I often use the following code.

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
if 'restore' in sys.argv:
    saver.restore(sess, '/media/chase/98d61322-9ea7-473e-b835-8739c77d1e1e/model.chk')
else:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

This code works fine when I am using the thensorflow RNN classes which create variables inside of them.